# The code don't work in android java WHY?

Tags: android

hello i'm trying to make on every button pres to go `"+3"`
i'm doing like this but the code don't work just on the first press its showing me `"3"` and on next click don't, its stacking somehow please tell me what to do ?

```
int Health =+ 3;
health.setText("Health: " + Health + "%");
```

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you want the two statements to have different variables?

Comment: woops thats a misstake but it wont work anyway ...

Comment: Two errors: you're showing DogHealth not Health, and Health will always be 3 because it looks like a **local** variable.

Comment: Actualy dont work .. :/

Comment: Do you know what a local variable means?

Comment: yeah its working anyway ...  :)

Answer (score 3):

Each time, you are creating a new `int` and adding 3 to it's default value, which is zero - hence it will always be 3.

You want something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    int health;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    // in click listener
    final OnClickListener mButton1_OnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {
           ...
          health += 3;
           ...
      }
   };
```

Please note that I've used the standard Java convention of naming variables with a leading lowercase letter.

Comment: +1 but you should show OP where is `health` located. I'm afraid he will still put it inside the method with this code snippet.

Comment: @StefanRafa  Please edit your question with the new code you have.  Please only include the bits where you declare `health` and the `onClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Define your health variable in a higher scope so that after you increase it it isn't out of scope immediately:

```
int Health = 3;
public void YourMethod()
{
    Health += 3;
    health.setText("Health: " + Health + "%");
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks men working xD

Comment: @BLaZuRE Yeah didn't notice, fixed now.  It wasn't his only problem though (and I think just a typo based on him saying it works now).

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying `Health` and showing `DogHealth`

Comment: Oops @RaghavSood already pointed this in his comment.